# Object required error when executing the code

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error, qtp

I am getting this error in QTP when using GetCellData and Childitem.

These are very simple pieces of code, but return an error.

```
set mytable1=Browser("name:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").Page("title:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").WebTable("name:=Home","index:=0").GetCellData(7,2)
msgbox mytable1
```

AND

```
set mytable=Browser("name:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").Page("title:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").WebTable("name:=Home","index:=0").ChildItem(1,1,"Link",0)
msgbox mytable
```

Comment: I don't know QTP, but as the command is written, *probably* the `GetCellData` method does not return an object instance. Try to remove the `set` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an object variable. Remove `set` and you are set :)

```
mytable1=Browser("name:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").Page("title:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").WebTable("name:=Home","index:=0").GetCellData(7,2)
msgbox mytable1
```

Comment: Thanks. :) It works for GetCellData. I thought of using **Set** since the error message implied that object required to get the output. Can please tell me when to use Set? The 'childitem' part still does not work.